# Show download progress in a ProgressBar with C#

Tags: c#, youtube, progress-bar

I'm writing code to download a video from YouTube 
and I'm using **videolibrary** to do that. How can I connect the download task with a ProgressBar with C#?

This is the code I have so far:

```
private async void buttondownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog() { Description = "select your path ." })
        {
            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {                        
                var youtube = YouTube.Default;
                labelstatus.Text = "Downloading....";
                var video = await youtube.GetVideoAsync(textBoxurl.Text);
                //setting progress bar...............................??????

                File.WriteAllBytes(fbd.SelectedPath + video.FullName, await video.GetBytesAsync());
                labelstatus.Text = "Completed!";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at System.CompnentModel.Backgroundworker. You can move the download to a background thread and get automatic update capabilities (by the backgroundworker reporting progress). There are plenty of samples available from Professor Google. Try it and if you get stuck, let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Progress changed is not supported in videolibrary
but it is in [YoutubeExtractor](https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor) 
See the code snippet below

```
Thread youtubeDownloader = new Thread(delegate () 
        {

            FolderBrowserDialog b = new FolderBrowserDialog();

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { if (b.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;  });
                {
                    string link = textBox1.Text;
                    IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videoInfos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(link);
                    VideoInfo video = videoInfos
                        .First(info => info.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && info.Resolution == 360);
                    if (video.RequiresDecryption)
                    {
                        DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);
                    }

                    var videoDownloader = new VideoDownloader(video, b.SelectedPath + video.Title);
                    videoDownloader.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender1, args) => this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { progressBar1.Value = (int)args.ProgressPercentage;});
                    videoDownloader.Execute();
                }

        });
        youtubeDownloader.IsBackground = true;
        youtubeDownloader.Start();
```

Comment: Ok but the code can not able save extention file such as mp4 , mpeg...... or any extention

Comment: You van Chance video type > VideoType.Mp4